# void* weirdness in C

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

I am studying functions that accept arguments of arbitrary datatypes using void pointers. Such a function is the following:

```
void funct(void *a) {
    float *p = a;
    printf("number = %f\n",*p);
}
```

Here is a successful invocation to `funct`:

```
float x = 1.0f;
funct(&x);
```

`x` is declared to be a float and then its pointer, namely `&x` (which is of type `float*`) is passed to `funct`; quite straightforward!

There is however yet another way to declare a variable in C and get its pointer. This is:

```
float *p;
*p = 1.0f;
```

But then the call `funct(&x);` returns a `Segmentation fault: 11`! How is that possible?

Additionally, assume that I want to create a method that accepts a "number" (i.e. float, integer, double, float or anything else (e.g. even u_short)) and adds 1 to it. What would the most versatile implementation possibly be? Should I consider the following prototype:

```
void add_one(void* x);
```

?

Comment: You need to read an intro to C. That is not how pointers work.

Comment: `float *p = 1;` : I *seriously* don't think this does what you think it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I  must make something clear. `float *p` and `float* p` are equivalent statements. If you're a beginner in C, I recommend that you write the latter instead of the former, because it makes clearer what the type is and what the variable is - it will save you a lot of confusion in the future. With that in mind, please remember that in the following block `p`, not `*p`, is the variable.

```
float* p;
*p = 1.0f;
```

The first line allocates a `float*` on the stack. As it happens with all variables allocated on the stack, its initial value is *undefined* (most probably garbage). This is not exclusive to pointers: even if you allocate an `int` and you don't initialize it, it will have an undefined value.

The same happens with `p`, so you should think of `p` as containing random data initially. If `p` contains random data and it's a pointer, it means that it's *pointing* to a random address. Attempting (in the second line) to write the value `1.0f` (or anything else) to that random address will almost always cause a segmentation fault, because a random address at any given time has little chance of belonging to your program.

Comment: Excellent comment and thoroughly explanatory! Thanks a lot and, indeed, I'm a beginner in C.

Comment: One question - Does the same principle hold true for `char*`? For instance at http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/krnotes/sx8e.html the author uses the statements: `char *p = "abc";`.

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind that `char *p = ...` is equivalent to `char *p` and `p = ...`, (*not* `char *p` and `*p = ...`). So, the author there is initializing `p`, not the address pointed by (uninitialized) `p`.

Answer (score 3):

```
float *p = 1;
```

is invalid; your compiler should at the very least have issued a warning.  It attempts to initialize a pointer variable (of type `float*`) with an integer expression (type `int`, value `1`).

There is no implicit conversion in standard C from `int` to `float*`.

If your compiler warned you about that line, pay attention to the warning.  If it didn't, play with your compiler options until it does, or get a better (more modern?) compiler.

As for a function that takes a pointer to an variable and adds 1 to it regardless of its type, there's really no way to do that in C.  Conceivably you could write a function that takes a `void*` pointer and a second argument that indicates its type, then use a `switch` statement in the function to decide what conversions to perform.  But it's a whole lot easier just to write

```
x ++;
```

In response to your updated question:

```
float *p;
```

That's valid; it defined `p` as a pointer to `float`.

```
*p = 1.0f;
```

The compiler probably won't complain about that, but since you haven't assigned a value to `p`, it probably doesn't point to a valid object. `*p = 1.0f;` has undefined behavior. If you're lucky, your program will crash; if you're *unlucky*, it will appear to work.

Comment: I edited my question. `float *p = 1.0f` throws the same error.

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis And... still not right. That thing is a *pointer*. it holds an *address* of a float, not a direct float. `float f = 1.0; float *fp = &f;` Consider that for awhile.

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis: That's equally invalid. Did your compiler print an error message for that line?

Comment: OK, so the right way to go would be: `float *p; *p = 1.0f;` ? Then `p` is a pointer to a float, right?

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis: Sorry, I hadn't read your edit. `float x = 1.0f;` is perfectly valid. `float *x = 1;` is not.

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis: What are you trying to accomplish? `float *p;` defines `p` as a pointer, but doesn't initialize it; following that with `*p = 1.0f;` will likely blow up (or, if you're *unlucky*, it might appear to work).

Comment: @KeithThompson Is it invalid to write (i) `float *p` (declare that `p` is a pointer to a `float`) followed by (ii) `*p = 1;` (assigning a value to the float to which `p` points)?

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis: Yes, if you don't assign a valid value to `p`. (Isn't that what I just said in my previous comment?)

Answer (score 1):

By declaring

```
float *p;
```

p is supposed to be pointer holding the address of a valid float variable. Here you are just assinging a number to p.

```
*p = 1.0f;
```

This would lead to undefined behaviour. since p does not hold any valid address and you are simply trying to dereference it.

Answer (score 1):

In `float *p`, p is a pointer to a float. You can't say `*p = 1.0` without first making the pointer p point to something. For example,

```
float *p = new float;
*p = 1.0f;
```

That might work.

Comment: I tried `float x; float *p = &x; *p=1.0f;` and then `funct(p);` and it worked just fine! Thanks a lot for the answer!